# Why does this throw and exception?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a base controller:

```
Public MustInherit Class InjuredWorkerController(Of TManager As IInjuredWorkerManagerBase)
```

Then I have a home controller:

```
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits InjuredWorkerController(Of IInjuredWorkerManager)
```

`IInjuredWorkerManager` inherits `IInjuredWorkerManagerBase`

Why does this throw a cast exception:

```
Dim manager = CType(filterContext.Controller, InjuredWorkerController(Of IInjuredWorkerManagerBase)).Manager
```

Unable to cast object of type 'MyClaim.Controllers.HomeController' to type 'MyClaim.Controllers.InjuredWorkerController`1[SAIF.Web.Mvc.MyClaim.IInjuredWorkerManagerBase]'.

Comment: GEnerics do not have co/contra-variance in .NET, yet.

Comment: Actually they do, but only in version 4.0, and only for interfaces - and you have to specify that you want your interfaces to have them.

Comment: @ekolis - Can you point me to the documentation?

Comment: Sure! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract an interface for your `InjuredWorkerController` to make it work, since co- and contravariance only works with interfaces and delegates.

This code compiles and runs (C# console app, I'm not fluent in VB.Net...):

```
using System;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public interface IInjuredWorkerController<out TManager>
        where TManager : IInjuredWorkerManagerBase
    {
        TManager Manager { get; }
    }

    public abstract class InjuredWorkerController<TManager>
        : IInjuredWorkerController<TManager>
        where TManager : IInjuredWorkerManagerBase, new()
    {
        protected InjuredWorkerController()
        {
            Manager = new TManager();
        }

        public TManager Manager { get; private set; }
    }

    public interface IInjuredWorkerManagerBase
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    public interface IInjuredWorkerManager
        : IInjuredWorkerManagerBase {}

    public class InjuredWorkerManager : IInjuredWorkerManager
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return "Homer"; }
        }
    }

    public class HomeController
        : InjuredWorkerController<InjuredWorkerManager> {}

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var controller = new HomeController();
            var manager = ((IInjuredWorkerController<IInjuredWorkerManagerBase>)controller).Manager;

            Console.Out.WriteLine(manager.Name);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[Eric Lippert's blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) on the subject is a must read.